# T-SQL cursor, variable is not visible inside loop

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am not sure what is wrong here, please help.

I am trying to loop over set of result and to use id's from set to execute another select query.

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @ID int;
DECLARE @Name varchar(200)
BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  ID, Name FROM UserGroups

OPEN @MyCursor 
  FETCH @MyCursor INTO @ID, @Name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM ErrorToNotify INNER JOIN ErrorMessages ON
    ErrorToNotify.ErrMsgID = ErrorMessages.ID
    INNER JOIN InterfaceErrors ON
    InterfaceErrors.ErrMessageID = ErrorMessages.ID
     WHERE UserGroupID = @ID 
  FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor         
END; 

CLOSE @MyCursor ;
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;
```

Comment: Please post the error message you are getting when running your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @ID, @Name` before the loop and at the end of the loop

**Edit**

My answer solves your syntax errors, but the correct approach is not to use a cursor. Check Rahul's answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will accept your answer in few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly don't need a cursor here rather just need to do another extra join with `UserGroups` table like below. Moreover, why you are fetching `Name` column in cursor since you are not using it anywhere.

```
SELECT * FROM ErrorToNotify 
INNER JOIN ErrorMessages ON ErrorToNotify.ErrMsgID = ErrorMessages.ID
INNER JOIN InterfaceErrors ON InterfaceErrors.ErrMessageID = ErrorMessages.ID
INNER JOIN UserGroups ON ErrorToNotify.UserGroupID  = UserGroups.ID;
```

Comment: Yes, correct. But I need to loop over groups because I have different select for each group, this was just example. Tnx for help.